# Random Concatenating Dataframes from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to use Pandas to merge some excel spreadsheets together in a random order but having difficulty figuring out how to randomize the selections.

Currently I have a list of names, heights, and weights in 3 separate excel spreadsheets. I have read those in using pd.read_excel and created 3 separate dataframes. I would like to randomly combine different columns and index them by a number.

So right now I have it like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df_names = pd.read_excel("human_male_first_names.xls")
df_weight = pd.read_excel("human_weight.xls")
df_height = pd.read_excel("human_height.xls")

r_name =df_names.sample(1)
r_weight =df_weight.sample(1)
r_height =df_height.sample(1)

results = pd.concat([r_name,r_height,r_weight], axis=1)
results


First Names Human Height    Human Weight
2   NaN 5' 2”   NaN
12  NaN NaN 240lbs
112 Robert  NaN NaN
```

I was hoping to do would be to randomly assign different indexes together, i.e. Index 3 on Names, Index 5 on Weights, Index 1 on Height. I am not sure how to best go about that.

Thank you as always for taking the time to read this and apologize if this question has previously been answered

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use random

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_names = pd.read_excel("human_male_first_names.xls")
df_weight = pd.read_excel("human_weight.xls")
df_height = pd.read_excel("human_height.xls")

r_name =df_names.sample(1)
r_weight =df_weight.sample(1)
r_height =df_height.sample(1)

results_list = [r_name,r_weight,r_height]
random.shuffle(results_list)

results = pd.concat(results_list)

print(results)
```

Comment: Upon running your suggestion it seems to be shuffling the column heads not so much the data itself.
 

Human Height Human Weight First Names

Comment: Hi may be i misunderstood your expected result. what am i understand is just randomly merging the columns from each excel spreadsheets randomly chosen columns row data. result of my code well shuffled  columns not just for name of column but the data below of the column(row data) So i can't get point you mentioned "The data itself."